# W10 Indexing paused on low power mode

Tags: windows-10, search, search-indexing

Once a upon a time, setting the registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager\DisableBackoff` to `1` would stop the indexer from pausing. Now though it seems that that is not enough.

[image]

On my home W10 21H2 laptop I keep the power mode setting to "best battery" since all too often I don't need the CPU to run at high speed and the system is quiet as fans don't have to kick in. The system is always plugged in, I just use the setting to keep the system cooler.

Now it appears that at this setting the indexer pauses even with the `DisableBackoff` setting. If I switch the power mode to "best performance" then the indexer starts again.

[image]

What additional settings do I need to change to make sure that the indexer does not pause even when running at best battery (low power) mode?

Comment: Have you tried a setting 1//5 the way along from Best Battery Life?  Does indexing start?

Comment: I am not sure you can, continue to index your drive, and have a setting set to conserve your battery.

Comment: @John The power setting pictured only has three (3) settings. Left most "Best Battery", middle "Better performance" and right "Best performance". I tried middle setting and it pauses due to activity, even though I am not doing anything.